# C# .net data mining from text to table

Tags: c#, .net, regex, database, string

Previously we used to get data on mail in the following format; we had to extract the important data parts from the text(body) of the mail and put it in a table.

```
 type         date               size
```

---

```
weekly    04/05/2012 16.03.03     388
```

I am capturing the value like this
First by an array:

```
string[] orderOfValues = new string[3];
orderOfValues[0] = "TYPE";
orderOfValues[1] = "DATE";
orderOfValues[2] = "SIZE";
```

and then in dictionary

```
sdValues = new StringDictionary();
```

Then extracting the fields by splitting;

```
sdValues.Add("TYPE", field1);
sdValues.Add("DATE", field2);
sdValues.Add("SIZE", field3);
```

---

Now the upstream have changed the data to send multiple rows.

```
 type         date               size
```

---

```
weekly    04/05/2012 16.03.03     388
daily     04/07/2012 17.03.03     14
weekly    04/08/2012 19.03.03     643
```

Since the number of rows is now dynamic, please advice as to how to go ahead

Comment: What do you do with the data after you parse it?

Comment: Also, you should use a class with three properties - Type, Date and Size, instead of the dictionary.

Comment: @zmbq I need to capture other stuffs like :from email address:, :cc:, :sub: and other parts of the email. There are atleast 20 things that need to be catured from the email other than these rows.

Comment: Oh, OK. But still, what do you do with the information after you parse it? It's impossible to answer your question without knowing what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I use 

                foreach (string keyVal in orderOfValues) 
    { 
     filecontent += sdValues[keyVal] + "|"; } to put the whole contents of dictionary to a flat file then load to Terradata via ETL.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you take that file, break it into fields and then write out the fields separated by a |.

Seems to me you need to go over each input line and do the following:

```
String[] parts = inputLine.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
String outputLine = String.Join("|", parts);
```

Write the outputLines to your flat file. You don't need a dictionary.

Comment: I need the dictionary to grab stuffs like :email file name:, :to:,:cc: and other data that can be extracted from the *.EML file.

Ok, so guess i will be generating n number of flat file entries for n number of rows.